# jqm navigation in Wp8 emulator?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

i'm developing a phonegap (cordova -v: 3.3.1-0.1.2) app with jquery mobile 1.4.0 (jquery 1.10.2), when running in Ms Visual Studio Premium 2013, any windows phone 8.0 emulator, the app can´t navigate from index page to home page!

The problematic link in the index.html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        (all meta-tags, js and css imports)
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="indexPage">
            <div role="main">
                ...
                <a id="btnLogin" href="#" data-role="button">Login</a>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the associate IndexEvents.js file:

```
$.(document).on("touchend",'#btnLogin',function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    console.log("---------------URL before: "+document.URL);
    location.hash = "pages/home/menuHomePage.html";
    console.log("---------------URL after: "+document.URL);
});
```

The pages/home/menuHomePage.html ("pages" folder at the same index.html level)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="menuHomePage">
            <div role="main">
             ...
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The visual estudio console:

CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted
---------------URL before: x-wmapp0://www/index.html
CordovaBrowser_LoadCompleted
---------------URL after: x-wmapp0://www/pages/home/menuHomePage.html

It works well in Android and IOS, but in Wp8 nothing happens! please any help?
and why is there a "x-wmapp0:" prefix ?

Comment: `location.hash = "pages/home/menuHomePage.html");` to `location.url = "pages/home/menuHomePage.html"` you have an extra ")" plus why dont you use jqm function to change pages?

Comment: Hi!, hanks for comment, the extra ")" is not in the code, just here in the post, i'm sorry. And, do you refer to $.mobile.changePage() function? so, it did not work either!